# How to understand 'defined' and 'declared' in Javascript variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, variables

I can't understand this error info in chrome console, the first error is 'let' declared variables are not accessible before they are assigned, but what about the following errors mean, 'Identifier 'val' has already been declared' and 'val is not defined'. My variable 'val' can not be used?

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried at the Question?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] after I `let val = 123` I can output and `val = 456` i can still output

Answer (score 1):

In order:

1.) Is due to the fact that you are performing "console.log(val)" in your REPL before you declare "val" (just in the line below). Re order these two lines and you'll be good.

2.) Is actually a side effect of your already declaring "val" in the line just above.

3/4.) You must first do a "var val" before doing "val = 456"

Most of these problems are due to the way the variables are being declared. Let is popping them onto your REPLs global scope which is making this more confusing than it should be.

Try running this code in something like jsbin.com and I think you'll find it much easier to understand.

Comment: Be careful-- you're conflating `var` and `let` here -- they behave differently.

Comment: Actually did that on purpose, since he's declaring var on the global scope initially. I was suggesting he declare it with var in his last example for demonstration purposes. Probably was a little confusing though without additional explanation, sorry about that.